# Dynamic display of columns and rows SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot, dynamic-sql

[image: Steps how should query behave]

```
iF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE #Temp;
SELECT distinct  ',' + QUOTENAME(a.Name) 
            into #Temp
    from tableB b
    inner join tableC c on c.Id = b.Id
    inner join tableA a on a.Id = c.Id  

    --select * from #Temp

        iF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp2', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE #Temp2;
        select c.Id, QUOTENAME(a.name) as Name, c.price as price
        into #Temp2 
    from tableB b
    inner join tableC c on c.Id = b.Id
    inner join tableA a on a.Id = c.Id


    --select * from #Temp2
    
    
declare @1row nvarchar(max)
declare @query nvarchar(max)

set @1row = stuff((select ', ' + col 
        from #Temp
        for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
    
            iF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tmp', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE ##tmp;
    
    set @query = 'select * 
    into ##tmp
    from
    (
    select *
    from #Temp2
    ) p
    pivot
    (
    sum(price) for name in ( '+ @1row +')
    ) as pivotz'

    execute(@query)

    select * from ##tmp
```

The Idea is to place attributes from rows to columns using PIVOT in dynamic order and than for each column displayed (eg. if there is 20 columns after pivot to create 20 columns with unique names COL1, COL2 and so on).
For each of those columns values should be like in third picture example. I tried multiple ways to finish task but I always stuck somewhere at the conversion of those rows in dynamic order (tried to combine while loop and count(@1row)).
I have query which is working but that conversion from column name to value is HARD-CODED and that is not ideal solution.

Please advice
Thanks!

Comment: `select c.Id, a.name as Name, c.price as price into #Temp2` remove `QUOTENAME`

Comment: @Neca24 Can you add your data  and table scripts ?

Comment: The data in those tables above is the same as in db. For COL1 value should be for each row NAME1 and so on